# How do I convert from ejs to jade?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, ejs

I want to change the ejs line to pug style.

ejs

```
<tbody>
    <%
         for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=rows[i].BRDNO%></td>
            <td><a href='/board2/read?brdno=<%=rows[i].BRDNO%>'><%=rows[i].BRDTITLE%></a></td>
            <td><%=rows[i].BRDWRITER%></td>
            <td><%=rows[i].BRDDATE%></td>
        </tr>
    <%
         }
    %>
    </tbody>
```

I have tried two things.

```
tbody
  each row in rows 
    tr
     td #{row.BRDNO}
     td 
      a(href='/board2/read?brdno==row.BRDNO') #{row.BRDTITLE}
     td #{row.BRDWRITER}
     td #{row.BRDDATE}
```

1. `a(href='/board2/read?brdno=#{row.BRDNO}') #{row.BRDTITLE}`
2. `a(href='/board2/read?brdno==row.BRDNO') #{row.BRDTITLE}`

But I have not succeeded and need help.

Comment: Please edit questions rather than trying to wedge code into comments: it's illegible. I formatted your original question. Twice.

Comment: Why do you use `rows` in your EJS and `row` in your Pug? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page: "it doesn't work" is not diagnostic.

Comment: The stack overflow is immature for the first time. Sorry..

Comment: Please use backticks to escape code so it shows up as code. But this makes no sense: the two code blocks you show are not equivalent. Please describe the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: i changed it as you said. And i want the pug code to be compiled like ejs that i uploaded. but it is not even compiled so what can i do

Comment: JJ, multiple users are pointing you to the help pages here as your question is viewed as having issues preventing an answer.  Please take some time to read the help articles about asking questions and take this feedback seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Pug 2+ is no longer support the following syntax for [**Attribute Interpolation**](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation):

```
a(href='/board2/read?brdno=#{row.BRDNO}')
```

If you want to include variable in attributes use either one of the following alternates:

```
a(href="/board2/read?brdno=" + row.BRDTITLE)
```

or ( only if your javascript env supports *template strings*):

```
a(href=`/board2/read?brdno=${row.BRDTITLE}`)
```